# How to force AVCaptureDevice to auto-adjust exposure

Tags: macos, cocoa, camera, avfoundation, avcapturedevice

Is there any way to force an `AVCaptureDevice` on the Mac to adjust its exposure? I'm using the camera to take a photo, and boosting the screen's brightness to throw as much light as possible, but this is causing the exposure to get blown out. I'm setting its `exposureMode` to Continuous Auto Exposure, but it doesn't look like that responds as quickly as I'd like.

Is there a way to call `[device adjustExposure]` or something like that? I'm **not** looking to manually adjust the exposure, which would be overkill here.

Answer (score -1):

You do have some control over the device's exposure settings, and the precise things you can muck with can be seen in [the "Managing Exposure Settings" section of the AVCaptureDevice documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009520-CH1-SW15).

Maybe you could try adjusting the ["`whiteBalanceMode`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDevice/whiteBalanceMode) of the device, and I see a few potential [useful constants in there](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/AVCaptureWhiteBalanceMode).

Comment: Those are the same constants as defined for Focus mode and Exposure mode (which I already mentioned I'm setting). Those settings don't give you a way to tell the camera to, at a point in time, adjust to changed conditions. I edited the question to make it even clearer I'm _not_ looking to manually adjust settings, but rather to tell the camera when to automatically do so.

Comment: @Dov
I just run into the same issue and would like to know how you handle your issue.
In my case, generally, continuous auto exposure works but  If parts of the image are very bright and others very dark, the image gets really overexposed....
When I take the image (the one has a vary bright and very dark part) using the iPhone's default camera, it adjusts the exposure in most cases. But my camera app fails to adjust the exposure maybe like 50% by chance...